# How do I solve this stuttering problem in the coroutine's typewriter effect through c# in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, coroutine, unity-editor

It's a weird bug. I basically have a list of dialogues that I randomly pass through a coroutine as a string. The string is converted into an array of characters and the characters are added to the text element of text mesh pro, character by character with short delays between them. Typical way for a typewriter effect.Anyways, it works fine most of the time but sometimes the text in text mesh pro is stuttered. For example, 'Hello' becomes 'Heeeelllllooooooo'. I checked and the text passed through the coroutine was fine, only the text in text mesh pro was messed up. So it's obviously a problem with the coroutine. Any idea what could be causing it? Here's my coroutine btw...

```
    IEnumerator TypeSentence(string sentence)
    {
        List<char> chararray = sentence.ToCharArray();
        dialoguefinished = false;
        var waitTimer = new WaitForSeconds(0.004f);

        foreach (char letter in chararray)
        {
            if (readingcode==false)    //Normal running
            {
                dialogueTMPtext.text += letter;
                yield return waitTimer; 
            }

        }

        dialoguefinished = true;

     }
```

I tried to pass it through as a list instead and also tried changing the wait time. But it still didn't solve the stuttering problem. What's weird is that the stuttering takes place only randomly. Almost like three times out of ten.

Comment: have you same problem if you write: `yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.004f);`  and put off the line var waitTimer =...?

Comment: Can you post the code where you are launching the coroutine?  Any chance that the coroutine is being launched more than once?

Answer (score 0):

I thought about the same thing with [Frenchy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7380779/frenchy) in the comments.

Also its more safe if you modify a string object first and then set to text component. This should works fine.
If you get any bugs please log "currentText" varible and share with us.

```
IEnumerator TypeSentence(string sentence)
{
    string currentText = "";
    dialoguefinished = false;
    List<char> chararray = sentence.ToCharArray();

    foreach (char letter in chararray)
    {
        if (readingcode == false)
        {
            currentText += letter;
            dialogueTMPtext.text = currentText;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.004f);
        }
    }

    dialoguefinished = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Was copying the code that @avariant asked for and found the problem. In the list of dialogues I had multiple responses and I needed it to throw a random one everytime. I did not want it to repeat a certain dialogue and hence loop through if the random dialogue chosen was the same as that which was previously chosen. That was where the problem resided, even though it was looping the same function again, it was leaking down to start the coroutine however. Makes sense why it was a 3 in ten time thing, because I had 3 dialogues so probability was 3/9 of getting the same dialogue and starting the coroutine multiple times. Thank you so much for the quick and astute responses guys. You guys are the best. I'm just fairly new to C# and even newer to coroutines, so I had no idea they could run multiple instances. Let this be a lesson to anyone who has the same problem in future. Here's the code btw... Note that 'return;' after I ran the rightanswer() function was what I added to fix the problem. Otherwise, the code was leaking to typethissentence(rightanswerresponsechosen), which was calling the coroutine.

```
public void rightanswer()
    {
        if (correctanswer.dialogues.Count != 0)
        {
            int randomindexchosen = Random.Range(0, correctanswer.dialogues.Count);
            if (correctanswer.dialogues[randomindexchosen] != rightanswerresponsechosen)
            {
                rightanswerresponsechosen = correctanswer.dialogues[randomindexchosen];

                // create a function to reward player here 

                wordPopulatorScript.clearslate();

            }
            else
            {
                rightanswer();
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("No options available to choose as a response to right answer. ERROR");
        }
        typethissentence(rightanswerresponsechosen);
    }
```